# problem in extracting number trought a file

Tags: python

I'm trying to extract the values inside a file so I can make an average.

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open("mbox-short.txt")
count = 0
total = 0
for line in fh:
    if not line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:"):
        continue
    a = line.find(":")
    line = line.strip()
    b = float((line.find[a + 1]))
    count = count + 1
    total = b + total
    print(total/count)
```

I can't use the function `sum`.
I try to use slice after the `:` and the output is wrong.

Comment: What output do you get and what did you expect to get instead? If you show a small example file we can better help you.

Comment: You want `print(total/count)` outside the loop

Comment: please provide few lines of your input and the output/error the current code produces

Comment: [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Comment: Did you mean `b = float(line[a+1:])`? You can also do `b = float(line.split(':')[1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `line.find(':')` you end up with an numeric value for where that character exists in the string.  You don't want to call `.find()` again to get the content after that character, you want to slice the string.  `b = float(line[a+1:])`.

Comment: wow!! thank you so much really. im just starting to code and this code gave me a lot of headache. thank you so much!